# Cannot unhide eclipse console toolbar

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse console toolbar appears to be hidden and I cannot find a way to unhide it.

[image: Original source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT1tX.png]

I've tried researching into this but have found nothing yet.

Can anyone help please?

P.S. the image above is just an example of what is hidden on my screen i.e. the console toolbar

Comment: What are you actually getting? If you not run anything you just get a couple of entries in the toolbar.

Comment: That's the thing, I have no entries; just minimize and maximize. This is the case even when I'm running something; makes it awkward when I can't stop a process or look at a specific log..

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have for this at the moment is to recreate your workspace; which can be a lengthy process..